# How to get the relationship info for two model instances in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a project with around 20+ Models representing tables in my DB. Some of them have relationships in between and I would like to be able to extract some relationship info from two instances that are related. For example the Foreign key that maps to the Primary key of the other instance and what's the value of this key that connects these two instances.

Currently I'm trying to get this info/comparison trough the inspect() [sqlalchemy.inspection] and getting the Mapper related to the instance:

```
instance_mapper = inspect(instance.__class__)
```

But can't find the exact methods in the documentation that will return me the key in each method used for the relationship and the key value.

**To make it more clear:** I would like to get the keys that are creating the relationship from both tables without knowing the schema of the specific tables but having the two Mapper objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy, Flask: get relationships from a db.Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206818/sqlalchemy-flask-get-relationships-from-a-db-model)

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566707/retrieving-column-from-a-sqlalchemy-relationship.

Comment: Both of these doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inspect the `local_columns`, `remote_side`, and `local_remote_pairs` attributes of a [`RelationshipProperty`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html). Given the following example models

```
In [2]: class A(Model): pass

In [3]: class B(Model):
   ...:     a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
   ...:     a = relationship('A', backref='bs')
   ...:
```

and some example instances that are connected together you could inspect an instance of `B` such as:

```
In [53]: mapper = inspect(b).mapper

In [54]: for rel in mapper.relationships:
    ...:     key = rel.key
    ...:     print('relationship', key, 'to', getattr(b, key))
    ...:     for lcl in rel.local_columns:
    ...:         local_key = mapper.get_property_by_column(lcl).key
    ...:         print(local_key, getattr(b, local_key))
    ...:         
relationship a to <__main__.A object at 0x7f8baf60b630>
a_id 1
```

and if you want to inspect the remote side as well, use the `remote_side` attribute, or inspect them together using `local_remote_pairs`.

Note that if you inspect an instance of `A`, then the local column is the primary/unique key, and the remote the foreign key column.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Just to confirm something else. If in b my foreign key to a is not called 'a_id' but something else (for example: 'to_a') <-- Just a dummy example. How can I get this foreign key? (rel.key is returning - 'a' which is the relationship) but I would like to get  'to_a'.

Comment: The inner for-loop is where the actual foreign key column and mapped attribute is looked up and accessed using the local columns used in the relationship. That is what should then handle your `to_a`. Note that the column might have a different name/key from the mapped attribute, hence the property-by-column lookup.